# Finding system constants to support positive solutions to a system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm well aware of linear programming methods to determine if there exists an $x$ such that $Ax=b$ and $x$ is component-wise positive. What I'm interested in knowing is given matrix $A$, what $b$s satisfy the requirement that there exists $x$ such that $Ax=b$, and $x$ is component-wise positive.

Comment: Unfortunately, my matrix is not invertible (rather, it has significantly more columns than rows). Is there a more general approach?

Comment: If you add the constraint $\sum x \leq 1$,
you're asking if $b$ is in the convex hull of the columns $A_j$, is that right ?
Do you want a program for any $b$ (exact / q+d approximate),
or some corners / extreme points of the hull ?

Comment: @denis What I wanted was a way of, given a $b$, recognizing if $Ax=b$ has positive component-wise solutions for $x$, and if not, find the $b'$ that is closest to the given $b$ via some metric, and that has a positive solution for $Ax=b$.

Comment: Don, can you describe your $A$: how big is it, how sparse, rank, centred ?
If exact methods take $O( m \times n )$ or worse, how about a randomized method ?

Comment: @denis I'm open to randomized methods. I'll get back to you on the nature of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This characterization might not be much use computationally, but it’s relatively clean theoretically.

By the Farkas lemma, there exists $x\geq0$ such that $Ax=b$ if and only if $b^Ty\geq0$ for all $y$ such that $A^Ty\geq0$.

Now, the set $C=\{y\;|\;A^Ty\geq0\}$ is a polyhedral cone. The dual cone $C^*$ of $C$ is defined to as 
$$
C^*:=\{b\;|\;b^Ty\geq0\text{ for all }y\in{C}\}.
$$
Hence, given $A$, the set of $b$ vectors you desire is precisely the dual cone $C^*$ of the dual feasible region $C$.

**Edit:**

The OP asked in the comments: given a fixed rhs vector $\hat{b}$, find the “closest” vector $b^*$ that renders the system $Ax=b$, $x\geq0$ feasible. This can be formulated as the optimization problem, with decision variables $x$ and $b$:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & \|b-\hat{b}\| \\
\text{s.t.} & Ax=b \\
& x\geq0
\end{array}
$$
The above problem is a convex optimization problem for any choice of norm $\|\cdot\|$. If you choose the norm as the 1-norm or the $\infty$-norm, the problem can be solved as a linear program. No matter which norm you choose, the problem can be solved very efficiently

Comment: Huh interesting, never thought about it like that. Unfortunately as you mentioned, Farka's Lemma is pretty hard to implement. +1

Comment: @DonThousand What’s your exact goal? For example, this answer shows that the set of rhs values $b$ is a closed, convex cone. Do you want a basis for that cone? A linear description of it?

Comment: Essentially, my issue is, I have a value for $b$ already, I want to know the minimum shifts I can make to it to admit a positive solution. A linear description would probably be helpful, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @DonThousand Ahh that’s an interesting problem. I would consider posting that as a separate question perhaps? Or edit this post

Comment: I didn't want to ask that direct question, as that isn't so much of a math question, no?

Comment: @DonThousand I think so. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ahh, I see the approach! Clever!

Comment: If I were to pick the $\mathcal{L}_1$ norm, this would be a standard simplex problem, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91748/discussion-between-david-m-and-don-thousand).

Answer (score 0):

The first idea that comes to my mind is to solve with linear programming the system $\min y$ s.t. $Ax - y = 0$. Then variables $y$ would output your vector $b$...

Comment: I'm not looking to minimize $y$ though. I just want to know what possible $y$s there are that lend themselves to a positive solution.